# Static char array initialization with simple function says length is 6, but shouldn't it be 1?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, undefined-behavior, strlen

I've discovered that this program continues returning 6 until I start returning 16 or greater instead of 1, at which point the program prints 0. Why? My intention was to use pass the result of a function directly into the static array initialization.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int ret_1() { return 1; }
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) 
{   
    char arr[ret_1()];  
    int l = strlen(arr); 

    printf("The size is: %d\n", l);     
    return 0; 
}
```

> The size is: 6

I wonder if this is undefined behavior generating an arbitrary value, or if there's an underlying issue I'm missing.

Comment: Replace `strlen` with `sizeof` and your code will do what you expect. `strlen` assumes that the array contains a zero-terminated string, which it does not.

Comment: Ah, that was my issue. Thanks, I expected initialization to handle null-termination.

Comment: @DaveL the problem is that the `arr` array is not initialized, it contains indeterminate values, therefore `l` will eventually contain an indeterminate value.

Comment: Initialization with a constant string will include the terminating null character (if it fits).  But there was no initialization, so the contents of `arr` are completely undefined.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Are you sure one could apply an initialiser to a VLA? I doubt it.

Comment: @alk Yes, the size would have to be constant to have an initializer.  For a VLA, initialization has to be done manually, following the declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Static char array initialization with simple function

This statement

```
char arr[ret_1()];
```

*defines* an array of as much elements as given by `ret_1()`, but leaves it *uninitialised*.

Then this call

```
int l = strlen(arr);
```

reads the (uninitialised) array's content/elements and with this invokes undefined behaviour. Anything can happen from this moment on.

To fix this do:

```
char arr[ret_1()]; 
memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr); /* Initialise array by (all) zero(s). */
```

After applying the fix, `strlen(arr)` returns `0`, meaning that `0` elements in `arr` are used to represent a "string". It stores the equivalent to `""`, the empty string.

### Note:

This expression `sizeof arr` actually returns the number of bytes allocate for `arr`, which in your example would be `1`.

Answer (score 3):

***TL;DR*** Yes, your code invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In your code, `arr` being an automatic local array, and left uninitialized, the content of the array is indeterminate.

Applying `strlen()` on the *array* invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you're trying to read indeterminate value.

**Solution:** As already mentioned in comment, you can use `sizeof` operator with the array, which deals with the *type* of the variable and does not attempt to *use* the value of the variables, thus saving you from UB.

Comment: So in C, "char arr[ret_1()];" is also undefined? Or are you saying if I defined it as a single character array, I should no longer have undefined behavior?

Comment: @DaveL: Probably a language issue, but what do want to express by "*pass ... into an array*"?

Comment: @DaveL no, that's not what causing UB there, the problem is with the use of `strlen()`  which is reading content of uninitiazed memory.

Comment: I see, thanks for the quick response. The null-termination was exactly my issue.

Comment: @DaveL it's not only null-termination, altogether you're reading an unit-ed memory, wich itself is UB.

Answer (score 0):

In cases such as your question `printf()` can be a powerful debug tool. For the sake of debugging you can expand your code, add this initialization and watch the difference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int ret_1() { return 1; }
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) 
{   
    int r = ret_1();
    printf("%d\n", r);
    char arr[r + 1];     //define the char array
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; i < r; i++ ) //initialize char the array
        arr[i] = '0';   
    arr[r] = '\0';       //terminate it

    size_t l = strlen(arr); 

    printf("The size is: %zu\n", l);     
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the basic issue - **Initialization** - there are few other issues with your code.

The return type for `strlen()`  is `size_t` so you may wish to do the below stuff:

```
/* Do the initialization of the array */

size_t l = strlen(arr);
printf("The size is: %zu\n", l); 
/* zu is the specifier for size_t as specified in ANSI C99 */
```

Also note the Variable Length Array(VLA) is an extension that may not work in all compilers. For example, doing

```
gcc -pedantic your_code.c -o your_code
```

should give you

```
 warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array 'arr' [-Wvla ]
```

Here the flag `-pedantic` warns about the gnu C extensions used &
`-pedantic-errors` flag converts such diagnostic warnings into errors.

Comment: Probably because you didn't answer the question. But also note that modern GCC uses C11 and not C90. If you are using an old version of GCC, compile correctly: `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`, or if you have a really old version, `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors`. If you didn't do this, the `%zu` format specifier wouldn't be available either.

Comment: @Lundin : Thanks for that. I usually go with `-std=c99 --pedantic-errors` whenever I want  to reuse the code in MSVC aiming for minimal rewrite.  Regarding the answer I already mentioned it is just a supplement to other answers but I really wish the downvoter leave a comment. But nevermind !